# How to join tables having many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to JOIN four tables together, one table is a joining table as two of the tables have many-to-many relationship:

[image: ER Diagram]

What would be the query to select DispalyName from User, Name & Description from Role and Permission & Description from Permission.

I know how to join two tables together, but my method of doing so does not work on this problem.

I have tried the following query but it doesn't seem to like it.

```
SELECT org.[User].[DisplayName], org.[Role].[Description], org.[Permission].[Description]
FROM org.[Role] rolee
JOIN org.[RolePermissions] rolePerms ON rolee.ID = rolePerms.RoleId 
JOIN org.[Permission] perms ON rolePerms.PermissionId = perms.ID
WHERE [User].[email] LIKE '%myemail%'
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Any code you want to show with your attempts?

Comment: Yes, I have added my one of many attempts to the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  - It seems that You forget to join with the user table

```
SELECT org.[User].[DisplayName], org.[Role].[Description], org.[Permission].[Description]
FROM org.[User] user Join org.[Role] rolee on user.RoleID = rolee.ID
JOIN org.[RolePermissions] rolePerms ON rolee.ID = rolePerms.RoleId 
JOIN org.[Permission] perms ON rolePerms.PermissionId = perms.ID
WHERE org.[User].[email] LIKE '%myemail%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join User

```
SELECT u.[DisplayName], r.[Description], p.[Description]
FROM org.[Role] r
JOIN org.[RolePermissions] rp ON r.ID = rp.RoleId 
JOIN org.[Permission] p ON rp.PermissionId = p.ID
JOIN org.[User] u ON r.Id = u.RoleID
WHERE u.email LIKE '%myemail%'
```